# How to get tree -a to ignore .git directories?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal

I love using `tree` to list directories, and I have a git repository with all my dotfiles. For me to be able to see them I need to do `tree -a`, but that will also list the contents inside the `.git` directory, which most people (myself included) never dare touching.

How would I get `tree -a` to exclude only the `.git` directory?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to use the -I flag to exclude a pattern:

```
tree -a -I '.git'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: For this particular use you can shorten it to `tree -aI .git`

Answer (score 5):

I was in the need to exclude `.git` as well as `.vendor` and didn't know how to specify multiple directories.

This works:

```
tree -a -I '.git|.vendor'
```

Comment: Very interesting, because the intuitive `tree -a -I .git -I .vendor` is only taking the last one into account.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a node based clone of tree called [tree-fiddy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-fiddy) that honors gitignore settings. It's pretty alpha right now, but it's working fine on my machines.

Answer (score 1):

Tree has added a `--gitignore` flag as of tree [Version 2.0.0 (12/21/2021)](https://gitlab.com/OldManProgrammer/unix-tree/-/blob/master/CHANGES). This should do what you need.

If you have a version of tree older than this and you have [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) installed you could create an alias like this to achieve something similar.

```
alias itree='rg --files | tree --fromfile'
```